# How to select current tag as DOM element in riotjs

Tags: javascript, riot.js

Is there any way to select current tag as DOM element without using id attribute?

What I'm currently doing is;

```
function addAttr(n,v){
  var ta = document.getElementById(opts.id);
  ta.setAttribute(n,v);
}
```

I'm looking for some direct way like this;

```
function addAttr(n,v){
  var ta = document.querySelector(this);
  //var ta = document.querySelector(this.root);
  ta.setAttribute(n,v);
}
```

Passing `this.root` works with jQuery but not with document.querySelector()

[Complete example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tKwQNdJO3nSUMi20f8vr?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. I moved my code in 'mount' event. So `this.root` is available. Now I don't need query selector. this.root works in itself.

Now I can directly use;

```
this.root.setAttribute(n,v);
```

I have updated plunker link for reference.

```
this.on("mount",function(){
  if(opts.fa){
    this.root.className += " faa";
    if(opts.selectable)
      this.root.innerHTML = fa_icons[opts.fa];
    else{
      this.root.setAttribute("faicon", fa_icons[opts.fa]);
    }
  }else if(opts.text){
    this.root.innerHTML = opts.text;
  }

  if(opts.transform){
    this.root.style.transform = opts.transform;
  }
});
```